# Start every window on all workspaces, with a few exclusions

Tags: scripts, workspaces, window-manager, cinnamon, wmctrl

I know about <kbd>Always on visible workspace</kbd> But I want *all* windows to have this as the default when opening, with a few exceptions.

The workflow I'm looking for is pretty much the inverse of how it works.
Show everything on all workspaces with a few (manual) exceptions.

Is it possible? If it requires some scripting I probably won't mind.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 with cinnamon, But afaik this feature is present in unity and most desktop enviroments.

Comment: Then what is the advantage of having workspaces?

Comment: I want most windows on every workspace, email, music, slack. But I want project specific browser windows on specific workspaces. So If I switch project, Only that window switches, but I can still manage my music

Comment: Could be done with a small backgroundscript, but would that be acceptable to you?

Comment: Yes, I know a little bash.

Comment: I don't know python. If you can direct me in the right direction. where can I find the info, which commands/files do I need to read? then I'll be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68296/discussion-between-janw-and-jacob-vlijm).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sorry, I just havn't gotten arround take a serious look and test it myself. I have not abandoned this topic. I still want to have it on my OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting case.

#### What we need to take into account

The concept is not to complicated: simply set all windows sticky, *however*:

- Since you want to exclude some applications, we will need to list those applications and check windows for their window class, to decide if we should set them sticky (show up on all workspaces) or not.
- The window list, as output from `wmctrl -l` also shows a few window types, like DOCK and DESKTOP, of which you shouldn't edit their properties in general.
- We will need to make sure only set *new* windows sticky, to prevent unnecessary fuel consumption.

#### Example script (python)

In the script below:

- a two-second-cycle loop runs to compare the window list with the previous one, using:

  ```
  wmctrl -l
  ```

  and subsequently extract the window id from each of the lines
- Subsequently, the script runs

  ```
  xprop -id <window_id>
  ```

  In which we can find information on the `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE` and the `WM_CLASS`
- If the new window "passes" these tests, i.o.w. the window does not belong to any of the excluded applications and is not of any of the excluded types, it is set sticky.

Since the script only acts on newly created windows, it will not add any noticable burden to your system.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

# excluded applications
apps = ["gedit", "chromium", "monkey"]


# ignored window types
ignore = [
    "= _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK",
    "= _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP",
]


# just a helper
def get(cmd):

    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, TypeError):
        pass


# initiate windowlist
wins1 = []


while True:
    # cycle time
    time.sleep(2)
    # initiate new list
    new_wins = []
    # get the most recent window list
    windata = get(["wmctrl", "-l"])
    if windata:
        # extract window -ids
        wins2 = [w.split()[0] for w in windata.splitlines()]
        new = [w for w in wins2 if w not in wins1]
        # check for excluded classes and window types
        for w in new:
            testdata = get(["xprop", "-id", w])
            if all([
                not any([ig in testdata for ig in ignore]),
                not any([app in testdata for app in apps]),
                ]):
                # set the passed windows to sticky
                subprocess.Popen(
                    ["wmctrl", "-i", "-r", w, "-b", "add,sticky"]
                    )
        # refresh the window list for next cycle
        wins1 = wins2
```

#### How to setup

1. Make sure `wmctrl` is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `set_sticky.py`
3. In the head section of your script, set the `WM_CLASS` -ses to exclude (you might want to remove the monkey, it was for testing purposes :) )
4. Test- run it with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_sticky.py
   ```
5. If all works fine, you could add it to Startup Applications, but make sure to add a small break to prevent the script from breaking on a not-yet-ready desktop:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python3 /path/to/set_sticky.py"
   ```

Have fun :)

#### Note

I tested it on Ubuntu Budgie (mutter) for 25 minutes without an issue. It should run fine on any window manager, but in case you run into an issue, just mention.

Comment: I made my own php implementation.  Couldn't have done it without your input. https://github.com/janw-oostendorp/Digsby